Hydrostatic mean pressure invariance
Does the hydrostatic mean pressure (Cauchy stress trace) remain constant when transforming it to a 2nd Piola-Kirchoff Tensor by using deformation gradient?
Thank you
Abdoulaye

Question: $\forall\boldsymbol F,\;\mathrm{tr}\,\boldsymbol\Sigma=\mathrm{tr}\,\boldsymbol\sigma$ ?

Does the hydrostatic mean pressure (Cauchy stress trace) remain constant when transforming it to a 2nd Piola-Kirchoff Tensor by using deformation gradient?

In other words, does a pullback from the current to the initial configuration conserve a tensor's trace?
The example you suggest is using Cauchy to PK2
$$
\boldsymbol\Sigma = (\det \boldsymbol F) \boldsymbol F^{-1}\boldsymbol\sigma\boldsymbol F^{-\top}
$$
and wonder whether, for any deformation gradient ($\forall \boldsymbol F$), the trace is conserved ($\mathrm{tr}\,\boldsymbol\Sigma=\mathrm{tr}\,\boldsymbol\sigma$).
Answer: not in general.
The answer is no and, in order to prove it, it is sufficient to find a single counter-example. We propose one hereafter.
Consider the purely hydrostatic stress
$$
\boldsymbol\sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
 -p & 0 & 0 \\
    & -p & 0 \\
    &    & -p
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And the volumic deformation described by
$$
\boldsymbol F= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
 A & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & A & 0 \\
  0 &  0 & A
\end{bmatrix},\quad
\boldsymbol F^{-1}=\boldsymbol F^{-\top}= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
 1/A & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1/A & 0 \\
  0 &  0 & 1/A
\end{bmatrix},\quad
\det\boldsymbol F= A^3.
$$
It follows that
$$
\boldsymbol\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
 -Ap & 0 & 0 \\
    & -Ap & 0 \\
    &    & -Ap
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which trace differs from that of Cauchy's.

Sorry @neerby i did not get notifications after posting it. Thanks for the demonstration !
